# Adding links to a Tumblr page

Tags: tumblr

I want to add links to my Tumblr page but do not know how, I've tried following tutorials but can't seem to get them to work. Would you be able to explain this in detail to allow me to post links?

Answer (score 2):

On the create a page section, click the button button that looks like a piece of a chain.

[image: Piece of a chain]

Enter the address you want to use.

Repeat for all the links you want to insert.

To change the layout you need use the dropdown menu and change it from Standard Layout to

- **Custom Layout**: Using your own HTML style
- **Redirect**: Once the link is hit, it redirects to the page directly